# Static GPS delivered via standard antenna port

Tags: gps

I have a system that requires a GPS signal from a GPS antenna in order to function.

The system never actually moves, and will therefore always have the same GPS coordinates.

Unfortunately, it is difficult to get a GPS signal to this device in the physical location it is in.

I'm wondering if there is any hardware that can attach to an antenna port which would automatically report arbitrary GPS coordinates to the attached system. Essentially it would act as an antenna, but only ever report a single set of coordinates. Does anyone know of a product like this, or any other creative ways to get around this?

They software on the system itself can't be altered to not require a GPS signal or have static coordinates.

Comment: You're asking for a device that will spoof the constant data stream - the ephemeris - and the piggy-backed high-precision time signal, from each of multiple DOD satellites.  That *might* just be a national security threat, if it was possible.  Perhaps the more direct approach would be to rig an actual GPS antenna to the device, with a long extension. If it gets too long, you would also need an amplifier, but perhaps it's a start?  For a creative solution, we would need to know more about the actual environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using an SDR (software-defined radio). It's essentially a device that can be programmed to transmit any radio signal you want:

[image: Nuand BladeRF board]

These SDR boards are known to be able to produce GPS signals:

- [bladeRF](http://nuand.com/) (pictured above)
- [HackRF](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/wiki)
- [USRP](http://www.ettus.com/)

(To configure one of those to send out GPS signals, you could use for example [gps-sdr-sim](https://github.com/osqzss/gps-sdr-sim), an open source Software-Defined GPS Signal Simulator.)